# Visual Studio 2015: Display typescript compiled files stacked in solution explorer

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

In VS2015, my compiled SASS files (.css .min.css) are displayed stacked under the corresponding .scss files. However compiled typescript (.js .js.map) aren't. This makes the folders appear unnecessarily cluttered, and it's easy to accidentally open and start editing the compiled .js file instead of the .ts file.

Is there a way to get VS to automatically display the compiled .js and .js.map files in the expandable stacked style?

Comment: Those are output files so they shouldn't be added to your project.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Thanks, I've removed them now. For some reason I thought that the files needed to be added to the project in order to publish. However it's working just fine with them excluded.